# VuePress different layout on dev and build

Tags: vue.js, vuepress

Hi I have a problem when using the VuePress. During the `yarn dev` everything look perfect. But when I build it `yarn build`, It seems that there's a problem on the top margin.

This is the Dev looks like:
[image: This is the Dev look]

Now is the after build:

[image]

See that the title "Login Page" is missing on the Build.

I'm using this version.

`"vuepress": "^1.0.0-alpha.42"`

Any ideas? Thank you!